# Android, Fast/efficient way of resizing a Bitmap/BitmapDrawable

Tags: android, drawable, image-resizing

I'm currently downloading a bunch of thumbnails in memory as a bitmap, resizing the bitmap via Bitmap.createScaledBitmap, and then using the resized bitMap to populate a BitmapDrawable, which I subsequently load into an ImageView to display.

As you can imagine, with a couple of dozen images this can be quite slow.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can speed this up?  I've tried resizing the Drawable via .setBounds, but that doesn't seem to work.

*edit* I am loading the bitmap into a drawable because at some future point I wish to utilize layers to add some text overlays to the image prior to display

Comment: What's the issue you are having with setBounds?


In my experience, the method you are using (which is the same as I use) is the slowest one for populating, but in the result you will have a smoother interface, as the loaded images are smaller (with setBounds, you are still loading the image at full size).